# Как согласовывать названия созвездий со словом "созвездие"?

Tags: согласование, терминология

Разные справочные издания предлагают различные варианты согласования со словом "созвездие" — в названиях самих созвездий.

1. Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова предлагает писать **Созвездие Орион**. В справочнике Розенталя это правило подтверждается.
2. Другие издания, например, четырехтомный словарь русского языка, предлагает вариант **Созвездие Ориона**.

Есть ли в настоящее время единый подход к написанию таких словосочетаний или действуют обе нормы? Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

1) В ПАС действительно использован Р.п. для названий созвездий.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=85#pp85

§ 178. В названиях небесных тел, созвездий и галактик с прописной буквы пишутся все слова, **кроме родовых наименований** (звезда, комета, **созвездие,** планета, астероид и т. п.) и буквенных обозначений светил (альфа, бета, гамма и т. п.), напр.: **созвездие Большого Пса**, туманность Андромеды...

2) Правильное название – это в первую очередь  дело астрономии. Если созвездие называется ***Орион***, то  не очень ясно, почему писали **созвездие Ориона**.  В новом словаре написание исправлено, и именно его  желательно использовать. Возможно, что со временем в правила также  будут внесены изменения.

3) О согласовании

В сочетании ***созвездие Орион:*** Орион – название, созвездие – родовое слово в роли приложения. Нужно ли здесь согласование?

В текстах встречаются **два варианта:** созвездие Орион и созвездие Ориона.

Примеры:

(1)  **Созвездие Орион** можно легко увидеть в конце лета, осенью и зимой. (2) Так, **созвездие Ориона** ярко светит ночами над европейской частью континента.

Также в косвенных падежах:  (1) Две яркие звезды **в созвездии Орион** это Ригель и Бетельгейзе. (2) **В созвездии Ориона** находится яркая и особенная туманность, называемая «Конская голова».

В первом варианте имя собственное **не склоняется** для сохранения точности названия (иначе было бы в созвездии Орионе).  Во втором варианте форма Р.п. также является **постоянной, несклоняемой**.

4) Возможно, постоянная форма Р.п. использовалась, чтобы избежать И.п. для названия в косвенных падежах: в созвездии (П.п.) Орион (И.п.).

Comment: Но вопрос был в том, почему "созвездие Больш**ого** Пс**а**", но "созвездие Больш**ая** Медведиц**а**" (а не Болшой Медведицы).

Comment: Спасибо,  я  неправильно поняла вопрос, ответ исправлен.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Как астроном, не могу пройти мимо двух деталей ответа. Во-первых, не очень корректно писать, что "созвездие Ориона ярко светит ночами над европейской частью континента". Вид созвездия на небе зависит от широты местности, поэтому в равной мере Орион ярко светит и в Европе, и в Азии и в Северной Америке. Во-вторых, эпитет "яркая" не очень уместен в случае туманности "Конская голова", так как она абсолютно черная. Насколько я понимаю, допустимы обе нормы согласования.

Comment: — Видите три звезды...Это созвездие Ориона, которое появляется на нашем полушарии только в сентябре. (Чехов). Итак, раньше писали созвездие Ориона. Эта форма отражена с справочниках и Розенталя, и Лопатина. Но в словаре Кузнецова (ред. 2014 года) появляется новая форма - созвездие Орион. Какое-то время они будут сосуществовать, но проблема выбора обозначена уже сейчас. С точки зрения орфографии  Р.п. неясен, Конечно, мы говорим "созвездие талантов", но почему созвездие Ориона? И  вопрос этот  к астрономам, и к Вам в том числе. Какую форму вы поддержите и будете считать правильной?

Comment: По поводу неточностей в цитатах.  Они были приведены только для того, чтобы показать существование двух форм в реальных текстах. Поэтому Ваши вопросы о некорректности их содержания относятся к этим источникам.

Answer (score 0):

Любопытно читать, какую роль Вы отводите астрономам:" Какую форму вы поддержите и будете считать правильной?" Мне казалось, что этот вопрос за рамками астрономической компетенции, так как относится к правилам русского языка. Если специалисты по русскому языку считают, что с точки зрения орфографии Р.п. сомнителен, то как астрономы могут на это повлиять?

С точки зрения практики могу сказать, что в подавляющем большинстве астрономических текстов, как прежних, так и современных, используется родительный падеж названия созвездия после родового слова "созвездие". Только в последние годы именительный падеж стал иногда встречаться.

Answer (score 0):

в Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке, Розенталь Д. Э.указывается, что астрономические названия не согласуются.

Проблема состоит в том, что не всегда удается определить начальную форму такого наименования: созвездие Возничий или созвездие Возничего (?), созвездие Большая Медведица или созвездие Большой Медведицы (?) и т. п.

Одно и тоже название в разных источниках встречается в разной форме.